# error : table.rows is not function i a using dataTable how to do it in dataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

i want to echo id of particular row on click of edit button  each row has his own edit button  in datatable i am using dataTable instead of DataTable how can i do this in dataTable

```js
function edit() { // my edit code 
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  var data = table.rows(tr).data();

  var rdata = data[0];
  alert(rdata[0]);
}

/// datatable code 
function createCustomisedDatatable(dataArray) {

 table= $('#example').dataTable({
    "data": dataArray,
    "order": [[0, "asc"]],
     "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": 0,
      "title": "ID",
      "searchable": false
    }, {
      "targets": 1,
      "title": "Name",
      "searchable": false
    }, {
      "targets": 2,
      "title": "button",
      "searchable": false,
       "render": function(data, type, row) {
       var returnHTML = CreateButtonDiv(data);
       return returnHTML;
       },
    }]
  });
}

/// here i am calling edit function 

 $('#DocListTable').on('click', '.edit', function () {

        edit();
    });

function CreateButtonDiv(data) {
return "<span class='edit fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true' id=" + data + " title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' ></span>";
}
```

Comment: create global var `table` and then set it as `table = $('#example').dataTable();`  in createCustomisedDatatable function, Or Pass table var to edit function

Comment: sorry i have done that but still not working

Comment: have you tried `DataTable();` instedof `dataTable();`

Comment: actually i have to use dataTable

Comment: `dataTable();` returns **jQuery object** where `DataTable();` returns **DataTables API instance**